# Angular, toggle limitTo via boolean (custom limitTo?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am trying to achieve a sort of toggle effect on the limitTo in angular with a predefined amount. By This I mean the data coming in has a value of "showMore" on it that is a boolean. If true, the repeat I am in would be limited to 5, else there would be no limit at all. I am wondering what the best way to approach a problem like this would be? So I have this for the repeat for example :

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in filter.values track by $index" class="builder-result-filter-value checkbox" value="item" update-filter="updateFilter">
```

And I would want something like this :

```
 $scope.limitValue = 5;
 <div ng-repeat="item in filter.values track by $index | limitTo: limitValue" class="builder-result-filter-value checkbox" value="item" update-filter="updateFilter">
```

But that filter data has the value on it

```
filter.showMore = boolean;
```

So I would want that boolean to control if it the repeat uses the limitTo: 5, or no limit at all.

I thought of one way to do something like

```
 <div ng-if="filter.showMore" ng-repeat="item in filter.values track by $index | limitTo: limitValue">
 <div ng-if="!filter.showMore" ng-repeat="item in filter.values track by $index">
```

But I'm thinking there has to be a more elegant way. Would appreciate any advice/input. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `ng-if`. You could do it on HTML itself using expression in `limitTo` like `limitTo: filter.showMore ? limitValue: filter.values.length`.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in filter.values | limitTo: filter.showMore ? limitValue: filter.values.length track by $index">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing that logic inside your controller. Something like this:

```
if (filter.showMore) {
    $scope.limitValue = 5;
else {
    $scope.limitValue = null;
}
```

And your html would look something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in filter.values track by $index | limitTo: limitValue">
```